# Homogeneous ODE Multiplicative-Additivity Distributivity Axiom

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

**Problem**

Suppose q(x) and p(x) are continuous functions. Show that the set of all solutions to the following ODE gives rises to a vector space. 
$$y'' + py' + qy = 0$$
Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be linearly independent solutions.

**My Question**

Most of my axioms for this proof rely on the multiplicative-additivity distributivity axiom but in my proof for this I use the exact result I am trying to prove. I will give the first few lines of my proof to show what I am talking about.

**My Proof**

Let $y_1, y_2, y_3 \in V$. We must prove that $k(y_1+y_2)=ky_1+ky_2$ for $k \in \mathbb{R}$. 
\begin{align*}
0&=(y_1+(y_2+y_3))''+p(y_1+(y_2+y_3))'+q(y_1+(y_2+y_3))\\[1.5ex]
&=y_1''+(y_2+y_3)''+py_1'+p(y_2+y_3)'+qy_1+q(y_2+y_3)
\end{align*}
The expansion for '' and ' is a property of the derivative. But how do I get around using M-A distributivity in the proof for M-A distributivity. Help!

Comment: The $+,\times$ operators being used here are the standard addition and multiplication operators, which always commute. So commutativity, associativity and distributivity follow automatically. On the other hand, if you were to prove closure under addition and multiplication, you would have to substitute $k(y_1+y_2)$ in the differential equation and show that it satisfies it

Comment: ahhh exactly what I was looking for thank you heaps!